# Why can't I put a slice in a conditional expression, and what can I do instead?

Tags: python, slice

I need to obtain from a list like `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` and an index number like `2` a series of lists in this fashion:

```
[1,2]
[2]
[]
[3]
[3,4]
[3,4,5]
[3,4,5,6]
```

I found that this for cycle works

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
index = 2
for i in range(len(lst)+1):
    print(lst[(i if i<index else index):(index if i<index else i)])
```

but this reduced form doesn't

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
index = 2
for i in range(len(lst)+1):
    print(lst[(i:index) if i<index else (index:i)])
```

Do you know why it doesn't work and if there's a way to make it work or maybe some other way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 3):

If you read the grammar for [slicings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#slicings), the colon (`:`) in a [proper_slice](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-python-grammar-proper_slice) is just a syntax element, not an operator or anything like that. So it can't be used in another expression (i.e. a conditional expression in this case).

Instead, I'd recommend moving the conditional expression and using unpacking like this:

```
start, end = (i, index) if i < index else (index, i)
print(lst[start:end])
```

Another option is to keep the same structure and use [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice), which creates an object equivalent to the slicing syntax:

```
print(lst[slice(i, index) if i < index else slice(index, i)])
```

Again you could use unpacking here to avoid repeating the name `slice`:

```
print(lst[slice(*(i, index) if i < index else (index, i))])
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `a:b` is special syntax that you're not allowed to use everywhere. If you try to write a line like `slice_variable = (1:5)` you'll also get an error.

Ultimately the `start:end:step` syntax is just syntax sugar that creates a [slice object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice). In contexts where you're not allowed to use this shortened syntax you can just replace it with `slice(start, end, step)`.

In your case that would be:

```
for i in range(len(lst)+1):
    print(lst[slice(i,index) if i<index else slice(index,i)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, you can write the loop this way (using `min()/max()`):

```py
for i in range(len(lst) + 1):
    print(lst[min(i, index) : max(i, index)])
```

Prints:

```
[1, 2]
[2]
[]
[3]
[3, 4]
[3, 4, 5]
[3, 4, 5, 6]
```